# Why error reported when using aggregation queries and export-csv tool in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: export, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When `export-csv.bat` to export data in Apache IoTDB, can I use aggregation queries simultaneously? I just tried to use aggregation function, and `Common queries and aggregated queries are not allowed to appear at the same` error appeared. What problem might this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only aggregate query or only original query in Apache IoTDB, then the data should be exported successfully. Original query cannot be used together with aggregate query. You can check whether there is any problem with your statement.